# node - lost in nested callbacks and scopes

Tags: node.js, callback

I am lost in nested callbacks:

```
var getTweetsCloudant = function(key) {

db.find({
    selector: {
        name: 'john'
    }
    , fields: ['name', 'text']
    , sort: []
    , limit: 5
}, function (er, result) {
    if (er) {
        throw er;
    }

    return result;

});
}

console.log(getTweetsCloudant('something'));  //--> undefined
```

This is part of my code, I can't give everthing as there are dependencies to an external module that connects to a Cloudantdb (db.find).
My problem is that console.log return undefined and not the result from the db.find callback.
I do understand that I get undefined because the callback (er, result) is asynchronous from the getTweetsCloudant function. I thought to create a function to be called by the callback (er, result) but the whole thing was becoming a small monster.

What's the best way to get 'result' calling getTweetsCloudant.
(My end goal is to export this function as module to be used by other modules.)

Cheers, Giovanni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.find` is an async function. This means that the result is not immediately delivered and the call is non blocking. The results are only available to the callback you passed to `db.find`. As the call to `db.find` will not block, the function will immediately return and not wait for the callback to be executed.

You can use a similar call back based approach to solve your problem.

Change getTweetsCloundants to accept a callback.

```
var getTweetsCloundants = function(key, next){
  db.find({
    selector: {
        name: 'john'
    }
    , fields: ['name', 'text']
    , sort: []
    , limit: 5
  }, function (er, result) {
    if (er) {
        next(er);
    }

    next(null, result);

  });
}
```

You can now use this function as shown below:

```
getTweetsCloudant('something', function(err, result){
  if(err) { console.log(err) } else { console.log(result) }
})
```

There are other approaches to deal with asynchronous stuff. [Promises](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html) and [async await](http://exploringjs.com/es2016-es2017/ch_async-functions.html).

Comment: Thanks Man.. fast and precise couldn't ask more.
What would you if you want to export this as module? Would you just just export the function (module.exports.getTweetsCloudant = getTweetsCloudant;) and use the function call (getTweesCloudant('somethin', function...) as you wrote in the importing module?